# Android : facebook not showing application icon

Tags: android

I am having a problem with facebook. I have registered an application with facebook, written the code for updating status via application. But when the status is posted facebook does not shows the application's icon on the wall. It only shows the small logo and not the big icon.

I have re-verified that the application icon exists in the profile page of my application.

Any help ???????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kkkkk So i came to know, that the icon needs to be supplied as parameters:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?display=touch&method=stream.publish&sdk=android&attachment={"name":"Facebook","caption":"Caption","description":"Description","media":[{"type":"image","src":"http://img40.yfrog.com/img40/5914/iphoneconnectbtn.jpg","href":"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/"}],"properties":{"another link":{"text":"Facebook home page","href":"http://www.facebook.com"}}}&access_token=105598479507160%7Ce6feebde80653a97ea24465a-100001583712186%7CTmgefqLbfhpczXwOxVRFWEsG1W0&next=fbconnect://success
```